# Get CSS property values from a component's "style" prop

Tags: react-native

I'm writing a React Native component for a library and I want users to be able to style it using the `style` property, just like `React.View` and other built-in components.

However, since my component is actually made up of a few nested views, I need to do some calculations to figure out what styling to put on the *inner* ones. For example, I might need to adjust the sizing of an image based upon the thickness of a border around it, or adjust a highlight color based upon the given text color, or in some other way infer some piece of styling from another piece of styling.

To do this, I need to be able to extract the actual CSS properties (like `borderWidth: 2` or `backgroundColor: 'pink'`) out of whatever gets passed as the `style` prop. This is fine as long as it comes as a plain object, but it may also be the result of a call to [`React.StyleSheet.create`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html). This seems to be an opaque object with all selectors simply mapped to numeric IDs.

How can I resolve these and get the actual CSS properties, in order to do anything more complicated with them than simply passing them straight on to a `View`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The built-in [`StyleSheet.flatten`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#flatten) function (or the identical [`flattenStyle`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/flattenStyle.js) function) can turn anything that can legitimately be passed to the `style` prop into an object mapping CSS property names to values. It works on plain objects, IDs returned by `StyleSheet.create()`, and arrays.

Example usage to check the width specified in the `style` prop from within a Component definition:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

// ... then, later, e.g. in a component's .render() method:

let width = StyleSheet.flatten(this.props.style).width;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to import StylesheetRegistry:

```
StyleSheetRegistry = require("../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheetRegistry"),
```

Then pass in the style ID:

```
var style = StyleSheetRegistry.getStyleByID(this.props.style)
```

Comment: This only handles the case where what gets passed as the `style` prop is the return value of `React.StyleSheet.create()`, but there are plenty more valid things to pass as `style` than that.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look on https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#underscored-styles

Style created via extended stylesheet contains original values in underscored prop:

```
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: '1rem',
    color: 'gray'
  }
});
```

In runtime:

```
styles = {
  text: 0,
  _text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'gray'
  }
}
```