# Why can't we check a style attribute of a react-native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to check whether color is white of an element, as follows,

```
if(styles.background=='white')
console.log("ok")

console.log(styles.background=='white') --> was false [1]
```

why [1] returns false?

Comment: Show the full file.

Comment: what is return of `console.log(styles.background)`?

Comment: @Banzay it was false

Comment: @DinukaSalwathura which one is false? `console.log(styles.background=='white')` or `console.log(styles.background')`?

Comment: If a style is inherited, I believe it won't show up under the element styles. Only if it is set explicitly on the element. Perhaps you can try using `getComputedStyle` if you have access to it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case styles is a StyleSheet object.

You need to use the **StyleSheet.flatten** function as below:

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});

var styleObj = StyleSheet.flatten([styles.container])

console.warn(styleObj.backgroundColor==='#F5FCFF') //=>true
```

To process a prop style of a component you could use it as below:

```
 let backgroundColor = Stylesheet.flatten(this.props.style).backgroundColor;
```

You can find the source code of the function here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/flattenStyle.js

Sources and more details here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35233409/1979861

Answer (score 3):

Just want to make sure the parameter passing syntax is correct.
(Note: the square brackets surrounding the parameter are not needed.)

For single form style sheet:

```
var styleObj = StyleSheet.flatten(styles.container)
```

For multiple-form style sheet:

```
var styleObj = StyleSheet.flatten(styles[1].container)
```

Then you can print it as a dict to exam the attributes:

```
console.log(styleObj)
```